# Ssh and sftp login via perl

Tags: perl

I have Perl script which is doing ssh and sftp on remote server,i am getting error while running the script. Error says You are trying to access a restricted zone. Only Authorized users allowed.

How is it possible to ignore these messages while doing ssh or sftp from Perl program?

```
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl ->new($remote_host,options ==> ["BatchMode yes"], protocol ==>2);


$ssh->login($remote_user, $remote_password) 

$sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new($remote_host, user=>$remote_user,password =>$remote_password) 

./HcSGSN.pl You are trying to access a restricted zone. Only Authorized Users allowed.
```

Manually ssh and sftp

```
$ ssh pocsoc@<ip> You are trying to access a restricted zone. Only Authorized Users allowed. pocsoc@<ip> password: 
sftp pocsoc@<ip> Connecting to 10.210.9.17... You are trying to access a restricted zone. Only Authorized Users allowed. pocsoc@<ip> password
```

Comment: Add your code please.

Comment: my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl ->new($remote_host,options ==> ["BatchMode yes"], protocol ==>2);

Comment: $ssh->login($remote_user, $remote_password)

Comment: Please add the code to your question using the edit function. Is the content of `$remote_user` and `$remote_password` correct?

Comment: yes , content is fine i checked it using connection on localhost.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just ignore these messages. These messages means that you need to provide `username` and `password` while doing ssh or sftp and also those username and password which are authorized to access the server. When you start providing them you will get access otherwise no access.

Comment: yes, true but i am able to login manually without script and messages displayed there also .

Comment: @Aks Please add the code you are trying to use. Also you are able to login in the machine and message displays or you are trying to login in the machine and message displays.

Comment: code added above, i am able to log into the machine manually and message displayes there also like below   ssh abc@10.123.121.11 , messgaes displayes and then password prompt also comes, so i am into the system. But same thing is i guess not being done by perl script , and i need to ignore those messages